# Print function is working before scanning

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm working on simple Library Book Log system. I try add book and delete book from system. But I have a proplem in there. When I try to start program. 
Program is printing next line before scanning book name. How I can fix it?

```
if(x==1)
        {
            operation.addBook();
        }
```

---

```
 String[] bookshelf = new String[1000];



        //METHODS
        public void addBook()
        {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter shelf number which you want to add book: " );
            int a = scan.nextInt();


            if (bookshelf[a-1]==null)
            {
                System.out.print("Enter book's name which you want to add: ");
                bookshelf[a-1] = scan.nextLine();


                System.out.println(bookshelf[a-1] + " added to shelf " + a + " successfully");
            }

            else
            {
                System.out.println("This shelf full already");
            }
        }
```

---

OUTPUT:

```
Welcome to LibrarySystem
1-Add book
2-Borrow book
Choose operation number what you want: 1
Enter shelf number which you want to add book: 
1
Enter book's name which you want to add:  added to shelf 1 successfully
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo)

Comment: call scan.nextLine() right after you set a and before the if to clear out the end of line character

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo

Answer (score -1):

- Have two separate scanner objects to handle integer and string.
- Fire a blank Scanner.nextLine call after Scanner.nextInt or Scanner.nextFoo to consume rest of that line including newline
- Or, it would be even better, if you read the input through Scanner.nextLine and convert your input to the proper format you need. For examples, to an integer using Integer.parseInt(String) method.